# how to access steps available in other cucumber project in current cucumber project

Tags: cucumber

Please help me understand accessing steps available in other cucumber projects in current cucumber project.
i have tried glue option as well and i also have added other cucumber project jar file in maven dependencies but could not make it work.

Below is the feature file of project1:
        Feature: To test cucumber test is running
        I want to run a sample feature file.

```
     Scenario: cucumber setup

    Given sample feature file is ready1
    When I run the feature file1
    Then run should be successful1

    Scenario: cucumber setup for cucmbertestautomation2

    Given sample feature file is ready2
    When I run the feature file2
    Then run should be successful2
```

"Given sample feature file is ready2" step is available in project2.

and project1 (cucumbertestautomation1) POM have project2(cucumbertestautomation2) as dependency:
        
            com.celcom
            cucumbertestautomation2
            0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Still the step "Given sample feature file is ready2" is not recognized which is there in the project2 (cucumbertestautomation2) which is added as dependency.

Answer (score 2):

The steps Cucumber will search for just live in a package, or a sub-package from the runner.

If you have steps from somewhere else, added as a dependency through a jar or similar, then these steps will be found.

They way to re-use steps is therefore to package the steps in a jar and add that jar as a dependency. You can use Maven for creating the jar.

Comment: do i need to add project2 step definitions in project1?

Comment: It depends on where you want re-use them. I would be careful not to create a cyclic dependecy chain. If the steps from proj1 and proj2 should be possible to use in all projects, I would create a common library with steps that both proj1 and proj2 depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber only knows how to read and execute your feature files because of the step definition files usually defined with in a `steps` directory and called something like `step_definitions.rb` That is where your feature statements are captured by regular expressions and translated to Ruby code.

My suggestion would be to include the step definitions from Project 2 into your steps directory in Project 1.

Comment: Thank you for reply. You mean to say import  project2 steps in to project1 like this : "import com.celcom.cucumbertestautomation2.steps.*;"

Comment: do you want me to share the code?? I can . May be i can share in git.